# orders the objects received from firebase in an array

Tags: firebase

I am developing an application with React-native and I am using firebase in the backend. the problem is that I am not able to recover the elements of my Realtime database in order of arriving. each time I launch my application the order of loading data is always different. I have thought of implementing the sorted quick to try to sort the object array received from firebase before display in my app but I received this error code: '' TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'array.length') ''. here is the code recovery of firebase objects
`import database from
'@ react-native-firebase / database';

export const getAllPublications = async () => {
let list = [];

```
await database ()
    .ref ('/ publications')
    .once ('value')
    .then (snapshot => {
        for (const pub in snapshot.val ()) {
            if (snapshot.val (). hasOwnProperty (pub)) {
                const element = snapshot.val () [pub];
                if (element) {
                    list.push ({id: pub, ... element});
                }
            }
        }
    });

     

return list;
```

} `

here my function to try to sort the table received from firebase

`export const quickSort = (array) => {

```
if (array.length <2) {
    return array;
  }

  var pivot = array [0];
  var lesserArray = [];
  var greaterArray = [];
  var date1 = new Date (pivot.timeago);
  for (var i = 1; i <array.length; i ++) {

  var date2 = new Date (array [i] .timeago);

    if (date2.getTime ()> = date1.getTime ()) {
      greaterArray.push (array [i]);
    } else {
      lesserArray.push (array [i]);
    }
  }

  return quicksort (greaterArray) .concat (pivot, quicksort (lesserArray));
```

} `
after having received the elements of the base here is how I tried to sort them before having the error:TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'array.length')

```
const [publications, setPublications] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    getAllPublications()
        .then((pubs) => {
            setPublications(pubs);
           setPublications(quicksort(publications));
            setLoading(false);
        })
```

}

here is an image of how my database is structured :
[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3N7K.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If transforming objects to arrays is something you do often when querying Firebase, you can make a short util function.

So you could do something like:

```js
const transformFirebaseSnapshot = snapshot =>
  Object.entries(snapshot.val())
    .map(([id, fields]) => ({ id, ...fields }));
```

And use it as follows:

```js
const getAllPublications = () => database()
  .ref('/publications')
  .once('value')
  .then(transformFirebaseSnapshot);
```

Finally, put the pieces together:

```js
const [publications, setPublications] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  getAllPublications()
    .then(pubs => {
      setPublications(quicksort(pubs));
      setLoading(false);
    });
}, []);
```

Give that a try and see if anything changes.

Good luck ;)